# Getting an attribute error when the value is already assigned

Tags: python, attributes, attributeerror

After you get to the part when the program prints 6 it gives me the error that is mentioned below. Even though the value if properly attributed. I want it to print a 6 when the Mario.x_location value is equal to the LifeShroom.x value. Then after that, I want it to increase the value of the Mario.x_location by one whenever w is pressed.  Type yes than press enter, and type w to see what I mean. What am I doing wrong?

```
start = input('say yes: ')

class Mario:
    x_location = 4  #location of you

class LifeShroom:
    x = 4  #location of the object.

if start == 'yes':
  while start == 'yes':
    command = input('')  #press enter here, after you input yes. 

    if command == 'w':
      Mario.x_location += 1 #change Mario.x_location
      print(Mario.x_location,)

    rules = [Mario.x_location == LifeShroom.x,]

    if all(rules):
        LifeShroom = True

    if LifeShroom:
       print(6) #type w again after it prints 6 and you will get the error below.
```

Exact error that I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    rules_8 = [Mario.x_location == LifeShroom.x,
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: The code you've posted demonstrates some misconceptions about classes, and possibly misconceptions about other things. What exactly do you expect this code to do / want this code to do?

Comment: I see multiple flaws in what you are doing, I agree with @user10987432 that you should specify what you are trying to achieve. I would also suggest you study the basics of Object Oriented Programming, feel free to ask for some material if needed. You are creating classes that you never instantiate. Also, `LifeShroom` is defined to be a class and you assign to it a boolean value (`True`). Can you edit your question and explain thoroughly what you are trying to do?

Comment: I  want it to print a 6 when the Mario.x_location value is equal to the LifeShroom.x value. Then after that, I want it to increase the value of the Mario.x_location by one whenever w is pressed.

Comment: The error is fairly self-explanbatory, you are trying to access `.x` on a `bool` object, but `bool` objects don't have that attribute. You set `LifeShroom = True` hence the error when you do `LifeShroom.x`. I will also reiterate, this code demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of classes in Python.

Comment: Oh, I forgot you can't set a class to a bool. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say that you are doing a infinite loop. There is no scape for the while loop.

In the first if-statement isn't runned the first if (`if command == 'w':`), but runs the other two. In the first one, it destroies your class (`LifeShroom = True`). But it is True, so it will run the third. Your variable LifeShroom is not more a class but a boolean (True).

Next loop there is no more LifeShroom class, so no LifeShroom.x class atribute.